# commands ran from Makefile are buffered, and don't print output imediately

Tags: shell, sed, rsync, make

when I run following command in shell, I see the `rsync` output real-time, as the files are being transfered:

```
rsync --out-format="%n" --info=name1,del2 -rt /foo bar | sed '\@/mmc/@d' | grcat /usr/share/grc/conf.rsync
```

but when I have same command in `Makefile`, it seems to buffer the output, and only spits everything at the end. I even added `-u` to `sed` to make sure `sed` is unbuffered. I also added `.ONESHELL:` just in case that makes any difference:

```
.ONESHELL:

@rsync --out-format="%n" --info=name1,del2 -rt /foo bar | sed -u '\@/mmc/@d' | grcat /usr/share/grc/conf.rsync
```

but still `rsync` ran from `Makefile` does not print the transferred files real-time.

what is causing this ?

## UPDATE:

adding `--outbuf=N` to `rsync` does not change anything either.

It looks to me, `make` is going out of its way to actively buffer whatever commands I am running from `Makefile`.

How can I stop this behavior?

Comment: Did you try adding `--outbuf=None` to rsync?

Comment: @stoney - adding `--outbuf=N` to `rsync` does not change anything

Comment: It's `sed` not buffering its output in `rsync | sed | grcat` run from the shell that is rather surprising. Do you have a `alias sed='sed -u'` or `alias sed='stdbuf -oL sed` by any chance? What's the output of `type sed`?

Comment: Or is your whole shell running under `stdbuf`? What's the output of `printenv _STDBUF_O LD_PRELOAD`?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas - no, I don't have any aliases for sed. `sed is /usr/bin/sed` and I am not preloading (`printenv _STDBUF_O LD_PRELOAD` does not show anything). The shell I tested it in is `/bin/dash`. In my script, the whole chain of commands runs in real time unbuffered.

Comment: Begin by elimination.  Check which of the commands in your pipe is buffered. What happens if you replace the `grcat` command at the end with something else (for instance, `nl`)? What happens if you remove it completely? What happens if you remove only the `sed` command in the middle? Or if you remove all the commands in the pipes, both `sed` and `grcat`? Find out which of the commands in your pipe is responsible for this buffering bottleneck.

Comment: Do you use colormake?

Comment: It feels like a long-shot. But have you double checked if the behaviour with `/bin/sh` rather than your regular shell? [Make uses that by default](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html) and not your regular zsh or bash. I don't think shells meddle with pipes beyond creating them, but the pipeline is created by a different binary, so it's hypothetically possible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be not with `rsync` but with `sed`, which (quite reasonably) buffers at any opportunity.

Here is my test `Makefile`

```
rm:
    rm -rf /tmp/etc.test

test1: rm
    rsync -av --bwlimit=50 /etc/ localhost:/tmp/etc.test | nl -p -ba

test2: rm
    rsync -av --bwlimit=50 /etc/ localhost:/tmp/etc.test 2>&1 | sed 's!^!RSYNC>  !g' | nl -p -ba

test3: rm
    rsync -av --bwlimit=50 /etc/ localhost:/tmp/etc.test 2>&1 | sed -u 's!^!RSYNC>  !g' | nl -p -ba
```

With `make test1` I get a real-time display of information. With `make test2` I get buffered output. However, with `make test3` I see staggered output (not as buffered as `test2` but not as smooth as `test1`). Empirically, a solution is to trick `sed` (not `rsync`) into believing that its output is not to be buffered:

```
stdbuf -oL sed …
```

Extending `Makefile`,

```
test4: rm
    rsync -av --bwlimit=50 /etc/ localhost:/tmp/etc.test 2>&1 | stdbuf -oL sed 's!^!RSYNC>  !g' | nl -p -ba
```

and testing with `make test4` I see immediate output much like `test1`. I cannot explain why `test3` (using `sed -u`) differs from this solution, but it does. At least on my Pi-based testbed.

Comment: The OP mentions they tried `sed -u` which would be the equivalent of `stdbuf -i1 -o0 sed` (reads the input 1 byte at a time and does not buffer its output at all)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I can't account for that. I've extended my answer with my results of `sed -u` vs `stdbuf -oL sed` - which are different

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas - adding `-u` option to `sed`, or calling `sed` with `stdbuf -oL` has no effect. Only when I remove the last part (grcat) from the pipe, does make print the output real time, as the files are copied

Comment: @400theCat do you get the same results as I do with my test scenario? If not, the culprit is likely to be `grcat` as that's that part I replaced with `nl` (I don't have `grcat` installed)

Comment: @roaima - since the command pipeline runs fine outside of make, I suspect make is the culprit, or some interaction of make and grcat. If I remove the grcat part in make, then there is no buffering. But I need grcat to colorize the output

Comment: @400theCat park your real life issue a moment, please. Do you get the same results from my test Makefile as I do? I'm trying to understand where else to partition the problem to get you a result. (Change the `rsync` to use a different target if you need to, but I've used `localhost` and `--bwlimit=50` to generate a relatively slow output.)

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to run the command like:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e make .....
```

or with `unbuffer`

```
unbuffer make ...
```